# Showing that $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$ is continous at $(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How can I show that $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$ is continous at $(x_0,y_0)$ by the precise definition of the limit ($\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition)?

Fix $\epsilon>0$. We need to find $\delta>0$ (in terms of $\epsilon$) such that for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$
$$
0<|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|<\delta\Longrightarrow|(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)-(x_0^2+y_0^2,x_0^2-y_0^2)|<\epsilon
$$
I can see that
$$
|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|=|(x-x_0,y-y_0)|=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}
$$
and that
$$
\begin{align}
|(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)-(x_0^2+y_0^2,x_0^2-y_0^2)|&=|(x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2,x^2-y^2-x_0^2+y_0^2)|\\
&=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2)^2+(x^2-y^2-x_0^2+y_0^2)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(x^2-x_0^2)^2+(y^2-y_0^2)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2(x+x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2(y+y_0)^2}
\end{align}
$$
and then I am not sure what to do next as the expression somehow looks messy.

Answer (score 1):

For $|(x,y)-(x_{0},y_{0})|<\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon\}$, then $|x-x_{0}|<1$ and $|y-y_{0}|<1$, so $|x+x_{0}|\leq|x-x_{0}|+2|x_{0}|<1+2|x_{0}|$, similar to $|y+y_{0}|<1+2|y_{0}|$, then 
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{|x-x_{0}|^{2}|x+x_{0}|^{2}+|y-y_{0}|^{2}|y+y_{0}|^{2}}\\
&\leq\sqrt{1+2|x_{0}|+1+2|y_{0}|}\sqrt{|x-x_{0}|^{2}+|y-y_{0}|^{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2|x_{0}|+2|y_{0}|}\sqrt{|x-x_{0}|^{2}+|y-y_{0}|^{2}}\\
&<\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2|x_{0}|+2|y_{0}|}\delta,
\end{align*}
the rest should be easy.